# Join, filling in missing key values

Tags: text-processing, join, merge

I have two files having a primary key value as a first field, and a corresponding value(s) as the remaining fields, and some primary key values are missing in one of them but are present in another, and vice versa:

```
$ cat jointest1.txt jointest2.txt  
a 1  
b 2  
d 4  
e 5    

a 10  
b 11  
c 12  
d 13
```

I'd expect an output that merges those files according to a primary key, either substituting the missing values or not, like:

```
$ joinmerge  jointest1.txt jointest2.txt   
a 1 10  
b 2 11  
c - 12  
d 4 13  
e 5 -
```

Ability to replace missing values with dashes or something is optional.

I tried `join`, but it says my files are not properly sorted:

```
$ join jointest1.txt jointest2.txt   
a 1 10  
b 2 11  
join: file 2 is not in sorted order  
d 4 13
```

What command should I use instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What implementation of `join` are you using? With `join (GNU coreutils) 5.97`, I can use

```
[0 1021] ~/temp/jointest % join -a1 -a2 jointest1.txt jointest2.txt
a 1 10
b 2 11
c 12
d 4 13
e 5
```

and the "plain" join works, too (but omits c and e). There is an `-e` option which supposedly lets you choose the marker for empty fields, but it appears to be broken in my version and only fills case e, not case c.

Comment: My bad, just missed the manual for option `-a`. Option `-e` is broken even worse for me, neither filling nor "e" nor "c" records. My version is `join (GNU coreutils) 7.4`.

Comment: @mbaitoff: I can imagine the commit log: "Fixed _inconsistent behaviour_ for -e option"...

Comment: By the way, where to report that "bug" if it is a bug indeed?

Comment: @mbaitoff: the manpage says: Report bugs to <bug-coreutils@gnu.org>; but don't expect a rapid response, I guess.

Comment: `-e` is not broken, it's just not documented well that you need to use `-o auto` for `-e` to work. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34655/join-filling-in-missing-key-values/37057#37057

Answer (score 12):

Try the following:

```
> join -e- -a1 -a2 jointest1 -o 0 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 jointest2
a a 1 a 10
b b 2 b 11
c - - c 12
d d 4 d 13
e e 5 - -
```

or

```
> join -e- -a1 -a2 jointest1 -o 0 1.2 2.2 jointest2
a 1 10
b 2 11
c - 12
d 4 13
e 5 -
```

I'm not sure if/how it is possible to achieve the same without the -o option. The -o option says:
first print the join field, then field no. 2 from file 1, then field 2 from file 2. Kind of sad you have to know the format of the files to get the empty fields to work.

Comment: It will also work with `-o auto`, then you don't need to explicitly list all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a perl tool for exactly that key,value problem:

[Pairing up the right rows: any number of files](http://r-labs.co/blog/pair-up-any). It's also available via [GitHub](https://github.com/religa/stats).

To execute it, you type:

```
merge -k -e "-" jointest1.txt jointest2.txt
```