# Join two files, keep key order of first file and fill missing values with string 'null'

Tags: awk, osx, join

I have two files--`file1` and `file2` that I want to join but some fields are missing in second file for which I want to insert string 'null'. One requirement is that the keys must be in the same order as in `file1`.

The input files and expected output result are as below:

```
file1.txt    file2.txt
a 7 nah      a anau
b 0 blah     c bau
c 5 bah      d cau
d 1 gah
e 0 hah
```

Expected output result:

```
a 7 nah anau
b 0 blah null
c 5 bah bau
d 1 gah cau
e 0 hah null
```

Comment: Solutions proposed in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34655/join-filling-in-missing-key-values does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`join`** + **`sort`** solution:

```
join -o1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2 -a1 -e"null" <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

The output:

```
a 7 nah anau
b 0 blah null
c 5 bah bau
d 1 gah cau
e 0 hah null
```

Comment: I am getting a different result.

Comment: give some screenshot and specify your OS

Comment: I tried again. My bad. I misread results in first try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `join`:

```
join file1.txt file2.txt -e null -o auto -a 1 2>/dev/null
```

It isn't clear from the man pages, but the `-e` option only works with `-o`.

Comment: This is giving error.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I used your example and got the expected results.  My version of coreutils is `8.26`.

Comment: I am on mac OSX. Unable to find join's version. The error message is: usage: join [-a fileno | -v fileno ] [-e string] [-1 field] [-2 field]
            [-o list] [-t char] file1 file2

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it with `awk`. I found that in my data as in the example, the second field of `file1.txt` has to be 0 for it to be missing in `file2.txt`--which helped. The script looks like so:

```
NR==FNR {
  a[$1]=$2;next
}

$2!=0{
  print $0,a[$1]
}

$2==0{
  print $0,"null"
}
```

Invocation:

```
awk -f merge.awk file2.txt file1.txt
```